# csrss.exe and dwm.exe eating huge amounts (2-6GB) of RAM

Tags: windows-7, memory, dwm, csrss.exe

These two processes (csrss.exe and dwm.exe) sometimes decide to consume enormous amounts of my RAM. This only happens when I have been away from the computer. I move the mouse to wake up the monitor and find 90-98% RAM usage and the computer is almost entirely unresponsive.

Task Manager and Resource Monitor show these two as the culprits. If I kill dwm.exe, the whole display shuts down of course, but when it finishes resetting itself RAM usage is back to normal. I have been unable to find anyone with quite this problem (found plenty of slow csrss.exe memory leaks on older versions of Windows). Microsoft Security Essentials is fully updated and finds no fault with my system. Below is a sample image from Resource Monitor and my system specs:

[image]

Specs:

- OS: Windows 7 Ultimate
- Mobo:ASUS P8Z68-V Pro Gen3
- RAM: 8GB (4x2GB) Patriot PGV34G1600ELK
- CPU: Intel i7-2600k 3.4Ghz
- GPU: Nvidia Gigabyte GTX 770 4GB

Comment: Have you stumbled across these articles? http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/what-is-dwmexe-and-why-is-it-running/ and http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001182.htm

Comment: It seems like you might have an issue with your nVidia drivers in my opinion. Can you do a clean uninstall and just allow Windows to use it's basic drivers and see if you still experience the symptoms?